# How to convert an input value to a session variable?

Tags: php

I just want to know how to convert an input value say an email to a session

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
session_start(); // at the beginning of your code.
$_SESSION['email'] = $email; // if the variable already initiated.




$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email']; // coming from HTML FORM with method = POST
$_SESSION['email'] = $_GET['email']; // coming from HTML FORM with method = GET
```

Then, go to another php file and do this

```
session_start();
$email = $_SESSION['email'];
```

if you need to destroy the session at anytime. you need to un set the session

```
unset($_SESSION['email']);
```

Comment: @SumitBijvani why ? if you are retrieving the variable from session you use `$_SESSION`. Whereas if you are retrieving the variable from an HTML POST FORM you use `$_POST`

Answer (score 4):

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
```

**OR**

```
$_SESSION['email'] = $_GET['email'];
```

**OR**

```
$_SESSION['email'] = $_REQUEST['email'];
```

Comment: as per @Othman answer. he miss to add
`$email = $_POST['email'];`

Comment: Thanks man, it is all sorted thank all

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you need to get yourself a good php book, and read a whole of a lot.

Just to put you in the right direction, firstly, the input, will be available in either the $_GET or $_POST superglobals, see:

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

secondly, make sure each page where you require to write to session, or read from session has a session_start() call: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

lastly, session variable are available through the $_SESSION superglobal: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php.

So at this point, you can write your input to session like this:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['email'] = $_GET['email']; // assuming your email came in a GET request
```

And in a different page, you can read the session variable like this:

```
session_start();
$local_variable_email = $_SESSION['email'];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your input type:**

```
<input type="text" name="email" />
```

*then*

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['email'] = $emailvariable;  
$emailvariable = $_POST['email'];

  //email is the name you assigned in your input type. 
  //emailvariable is any variable you want to assign.
```

*and in your different page*

```
session_start();
$emailvariable = $_SESSION['email']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  session_start();  
if(isset($_POST['email']){
  $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
}

OR
if(isset($_GET['email']){
  $_SESSION['email'] = $_GET['email'];
}
OR

if(isset($_REQUEST['email']){
  $_SESSION['email'] = $_REQUEST['email'];
}
```